# which is the best and easy way to display stock graph in android?

Tags: android, charts

I am developing stock app in which user can show stock detail and show stock graph.

i am using yahoo finance API to list and search stocks quote, now the i want to display there graph. i m searching since 2 day but didn't way to display dynamic data graph.

i have seen so many library but till i am not satisfied. because of all most library provide a way to display static data graph. in my task i want display graph with zooming facility as well as multi-touch support.

If any one can support me i really appreciate the person.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: This sounds like an excellent exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

- http://www.achartengine.org/
- http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/
- http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aiCharts.aspx (commercial)
- http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ (online only)

The first one for sure has zoom capabilities. I don't know about multitouch, though.

The google API [has some interaction built-in](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#interaction_using_events) and you could take advantage that it runs in a WebView, so you can use its own zoom capabilities. Since your app is going to require a network connection anyway, it seems like a reasonable option.

Answer (score 1):

AChartEngine does support multi-touch / pinch zoom.
You can add / remove data to / from your datasets and then call chartView.repaint() and you will get a dynamic behavior.

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

SciChart for Android supports Candlestick charts, and will allow you to create real-time trading apps.

Check out the [Android Candlestick Chart example](http://www.scichart.com/android-candlestick-chart-example/) or see the [Android Stock Chart Features](https://www.scichart.com/android-stock-charts/) for more info.

[image: Android Stock Charts by SciChart]

*Disclosure: I am the MD of the SciChart project, just so you know!*