# android, how to plot some values on the screen

Tags: android, layout, graph

Actually I have no idea how to solve my problem. I captured some data into an array, so the values present there look like that: `{-11, -53, -27, 50, 39, ..., ...}`. I just want to know, how I can show these values on the screen, in a graph. I have not yet any implementation idea, otherwise I would give some code snippets. Sry for that.

*additional information*: The data is captured from microphone and I use a method of `AudioRecord` calss to read into a short array (`public int read (short[] audioData, int offsetInShorts, int sizeInShorts)`). As AudioRecord read in chunks of data, I want to update the screen while capturing, but that's for later...

I just want to know, how I can show these values on the screen, in a graph. Which layout, just some point where I can start from. Would be nice if anybody can help me.

Thanks in advance for your help.
nyyrikki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need real-time updates, I suggest you to use one of the many chart libraries around. Check my answer here for a list: [which is the best and easy way to display stock graph in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139288/which-is-the-best-and-easy-way-to-display-stock-graph-in-android/6139832#6139832)

If you do need real-time updating, you'll most probably have to implement a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and do your drawing yourself. Check the [Lunar Lander](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html) example for an implementation of SurfaceView.